# pdf file not opening in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am receiving a pdf file as api call response from a node.js backend.The file opens  in browser window in an encoded format.I have  tried to download but the downloaded file has error opening it (error: failed to load pdf document).I am told the response body is base64 encoded.

Is their any way the pdf can be open /downloaded correctly.I am using react.js and is new to it.

**code snippet :**

import FileDownload from 'js-file-download';

```
export function getTaxInvoice({token}){
  const authString = `Bearer ${token}`;

  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.get(`${MAIN_URL}/rental_invoice`,{
      headers: {Authorization: authString, 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/pdf'},
      responseType: "arraybuffer",//I have tried with blob as well
      encoding: null
      })
    .then((response)=>{
      FileDownload(response, 'some.pdf');
      const taxInvoiceUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      window.open(taxInvoiceUrl, "_blank");
      console.log( response); 
      // dispatch(taxInvoiceLoadSuccess(taxInvoiceUrl));
      // dispatch(onViewChanged("rental_invoice"));
    }) 
    .catch((error)=>{
      dispatch(taxInvoiceLoadFailed());
    })
  }
}
```

**response from api call:**[image snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPabK.png)

Comment: Just a guess but try `new Blob(response.data)` (without nesting `response.data` in an array).

Comment: @justin.m.chase : Tried it .no t working

Comment: so the array buffer is a base64 encoded content? Then decode it and set it in the blob.

Comment: You may need to add `{ type: 'application/pdf' }` as a second argument to Blob then

Comment: @karthick : atob () function is giving th eerror: message: "Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."
ab2str() is returning data in some chinese language.

Comment: if possible can you post a base64 string version of your response in a jsfiddle or code block?

Comment: @karthick : https://jsfiddle.net/rem123/90mehLpf/ this is the pdf snippet without all the changes u have suggested.

Comment: the result of ab2str() is something like below:噊䕂楒砰橌䭍敊橌㥺䭍卍睁䝉椹条扰ㅌ䕂楒癁䝖㑖䙤䬰坚欵㉢煊楃杕楋煯楋杯浑湖坡朴坓稵塚お䕉㈹塚獊塙㙫䍉䠹け

Comment: @Rem Is the base64 string you posted the ajax response in string format or the array buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue.(My senior dev helped me).Final code is below:
install base64js and filedownload on npm .

```
export function getTaxInvoice({token}){
  const authString = `Bearer ${token}`;

  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.get(`${MAIN_URL}/rental_invoice`,{
      headers: {Authorization: authString, 'Accept': 'application/pdf','Content-Type': 'application/pdf'}
      })
    .then((response)=>{
      FileDownload(base64js.toByteArray(response.data), 'some.pdf');
      const taxInvoiceUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([base64js.toByteArray(response.data)], { type: "application/pdf" }) );
      window.open(taxInvoiceUrl, "_blank");
      dispatch(taxInvoiceLoadSuccess(response.data));
      dispatch(onViewChanged("rental_invoice"));
    }) 
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(taxInvoiceLoadFailed());
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of some code I have used in the past to do this:

```
function downloadURI (url, name) {
  var link = document.createElement('a')
  link.download = name
  link.href = url
  document.body.appendChild(link)
  link.click()
  document.body.removeChild(link)
}

export function download (url, type = 'application/pdf', name = 'example') {
  get(url, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err)
    const blob = new Blob([result.body], { type })
    const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    downloadURI(downloadUrl, name)
  })
}
```

It will download the file and create an object url and automatically trigger opening the file by programatically clicking a link.

Comment: This saved my life after about 2 hours ⁠— starting at 1 AM ⁠— of searching. Thank you, so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing
`FileDownload(response, 'some.pdf');`
to
`FileDownload(response.data, 'some.pdf');`

Comment: same result. the pdf is opening in encoded format and the downloaded pdf gives the same error